# Ways to make wacky chords

Tags: chords

Okay so I recently came across a website which demonstrated the possibility of finding a triple sharp or triple flat, which was just weird in the first place.

Question: Is it possible to ever come across a chord naturally (no pun intended) that would ever have more than a triple accidental (like quadruple, five, etc.). This means that by using one of the 12 enharmonic major/minor scales and any mode, would it ever be possible to run into that? Or would someone have to intentionally go out of their way to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible to do it "naturally".

We do need double sharps pretty often, and double flats at times.  But double sharps are most commonly needed to keep a melodic or harmonic minor scale diatonic (I'm using *diatonic* in the literal sense of "through the tones", or having one of each letter).

Let's say you've got a key signature of B, five sharps.  And you're in the relative minor, G#.  The harmonic minor raises the seventh degree, which is F#, so we need Fx.

If you're writing a melody, you'd have no need for a triple-sharped F, because you would just write G#.  So the only reason you'd need to raise that Fx again is to accommodate a particular chord.

Since chords are built in thirds, you cab consider each chord tone:

- it can't be the root, because they're never raised
- it can't be the third, because a raised third is a sus chord, which uses the fourth
- it could be the fifth, for an augmented chord
- it can't be the seventh, because raising that is the root
- it could be the ninth; #9s are common
- it could be the eleventh, as in a maj7#11 chord
- it can't be the thirteenth, because you'd write it as b7

So the only times you'd "naturally" need a triple sharp is if it's the 5th, 9th, or 11th.

Now we can work backwards:

- if Fx is the fifth, it's a B root.  But in key, it's already augmented: B-D#-Fx.  We have double augmented intervals, but double-augmented chords don't exist (because it would be a G#m inversion, G#-B-D#)
- If Fx is the 9th, then E is the root.  But that means Fx is already a #9.
- If Fx is the 11th, then C# is the root.  But that means your Fx is already a #11.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was very helpful and very thorough

Answer (score 0):

NO, in real-world music we see the occasional double-sharp or double-flat, but that's as far as it goes.

The experimental fringe do experimental things, of course!